# Navigation bar is white, while isTranslucent = false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have one main Navigation Controller, where I set the the background color

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

But, in that case my nav bar becomes completely white. When I set isTranslucent to true my navigation bar becomes transparent, but that is not actually what I need.
I want to have just blue navigation bar.

Just in case in my Nav Controller I have overried

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{ return .lightContent }
```

And in AppDelegate set tint color

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Commenting tintColor didn't help me either.

[image: This is my "blue" navigation bar]

Answer (score 5):

Use below code to change the colour of the navigation-bar.

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = false
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Comment: Omg... been trying to fix this for hours.. had been using backgroundColor instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set barTint color instead of tintColor

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```